# How to remove bullet points from a List group item

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am using the List group component to create a menu with my own styling something like below:

```
<div id="menu" class="list-group">
    <div class="menu-item menu-level-0 sub-menu list-group-item">
        <li>Fruits</li>
    </div>
    <div class="menu-item menu-level-0 sub-menu list-group-item">
        <li>Vegetables</li>
    </div>
    <div class="menu-item menu-level-0 sub-menu list-group-item">
        <li>Meats</li>
    </div>
</div>
```

How can I remove the bullet points that get created for each list-group-item?

Comment: Why is there an `<li>` inside of a `<div>`? LIs are children of ul, ol, and menu.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The bullet points are coming from the `<li>` element. It is a list item and has bullet points by default.

They can be hidden with some simple CSS:

```css
li {
    list-style: none;
}
```

Or like suggested in the comments of this answer, you could fully remove the `<li>` elements because they aren't needed here:

```html
<div id="menu" class="list-group">
    <div class="menu-item menu-level-0 sub-menu list-group-item">
        Fruits
    </div>
    ...
</div>
```

Comment: Or just remove the LI since it should not be a child of a div.

Answer (score 1):

If you change the code to match Bootstrap's docs the styling will not show the bullets. Change your `div` to a `ul` for your `list-group` and replace your `list-group-item` divs with `li`.

```
<ul id="menu" class="list-group">
  <li class="menu-item menu-level-0 sub-menu list-group-item">Fruits</li>
  <li class="menu-item menu-level-0 sub-menu list-group-item">Vegetables</li>
  <li class="menu-item menu-level-0 sub-menu list-group-item">Meats</li>
</ul>
```

This way you are not overriding styling and you are using the built in bootstrap styles.

Ref: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.3/components/list-group/

Bootstrap Example:

```
<ul class="list-group">
  <li class="list-group-item">Cras justo odio</li>
  <li class="list-group-item">Dapibus ac facilisis in</li>
  <li class="list-group-item">Morbi leo risus</li>
  <li class="list-group-item">Porta ac consectetur ac</li>
  <li class="list-group-item">Vestibulum at eros</li>
</ul>
```